# splunk regex eliminate final quote

Tags: regex, splunk

I have:

```
Row 114005: Requester Name: "RETAIL\S2343W01$" Issued Common Name: "S2343W01.retail.fakename.com" User Principal Name: "S2343W01.retail.fakename.com" Serial Number: "4c22be0100010002d317" Certificate Template: Client Authentication - Retail Desktops Certificate Effective Date: 12/1/2011 10:38 AM Certificate Expiration Date: 11/30/2012 10:38 AMMaximum Row Index: 114005
```

And I have regex:

```
(?i)Serial Number: “(?P<cert_SN>.+?\n)
```

Result is like:

```
cert_SN = 4c22be0100010002d317"
```

How can I eliminate the final quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(?i)Serial Number:\s\"(?P<cert_sn>\w+)
```

Or if need to capture empty fields:

```
(?i)Serial Number:\s\"(?P<cert_sn>[^\"]*)\"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `.+?\n` by `[^"]+`

`[^"]` is a character class that doesn't contain the double quote.

Comment: @akuzma: in this case, it is as if it is worth a thousand. Thanks